# The problem is with the function for displaying the results of thematic modeling in the form of a table

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I used the function to display the results of mathematical modeling in the form of a table. Initially, the function worked correctly, then it started to fall into error.
I was prompted that the fact is that panda has updated to version 2.0 and it was suggested to use concat instead of append, but the function still falls into error, what's the matter?

```
    def format_topics_sentences(ldamodel=ldamodel, corpus=textCorpus, texts=docCollTexts):
    # Init output
    sent_topics_df = pd.DataFrame()
    # Get main topic in each document
    for i, row in enumerate(ldamodel[textCorpus]):
        row = sorted(row, key=lambda x: (x[1]), reverse=True)
        # Get the Dominant topic, Perc Contribution and Keywords for each document
        for j, (topic_num, prop_topic) in enumerate(row):
            if j == 0:  # => dominant topic
                wp = ldamodel.show_topic(topic_num)
                topic_keywords = ", ".join([word for word, prop in wp])
                sent_topics_df = sent_topics_df.append(pd.Series([int(topic_num), round(prop_topic,4), topic_keywords]), ignore_index=True)
            else:
                break
    sent_topics_df.columns = ['Dominant_Topic', 'Perc_Contribution', 'Topic_Keywords']
    # Add original text to the end of the output
    contents = pd.Series(texts)
    sent_topics_df = pd.concat([sent_topics_df, contents], axis=1)
    return(sent_topics_df)
df_topic_sents_keywords = format_topics_sentences(ldamodel=ldamodel, corpus=textCorpus, texts=docCollTexts)
# Format
df_dominant_topic = df_topic_sents_keywords.reset_index()
df_dominant_topic.columns = ['Document_No', 'Dominant_Topic', 'Topic_Perc_Contrib', 'Keywords', 'Text']
# Show
df_dominant_topic.head(10)
```

error

`AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 20>()
18     sent_topics_df = pd.concat([sent_topics_df, contents], axis=1)
19     return(sent_topics_df)
---> 20 df_topic_sents_keywords = format_topics_sentences(ldamodel=ldamodel, corpus=textCorpus, texts=docCollTexts)
21 # Format
22 df_dominant_topic = df_topic_sents_keywords.reset_index()

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in **getattr**(self, name)
6291         ):
6292             return self[name]
-> 6293         return object.**getattribute**(self, name)
6294
6295     @final

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'append'`

after the change to concat

```
def format_topics_sentences(ldamodel=ldamodel, corpus=textCorpus, texts=docCollTexts):
    # Init output
    sent_topics_df = pd.DataFrame()
    # Get main topic in each document
    for i, row in enumerate(ldamodel[textCorpus]):
        row = sorted(row, key=lambda x: (x[1]), reverse=True)
        # Get the Dominant topic, Perc Contribution and Keywords for each document
        for j, (topic_num, prop_topic) in enumerate(row):
            if j == 0:  # => dominant topic
                wp = ldamodel.show_topic(topic_num)
                topic_keywords = ", ".join([word for word, prop in wp])
                sent_topics_df = pd.concat([sent_topics_df, pd.DataFrame(data=[[int(topic_num), round(prop_topic,4), topic_keywords]], columns=sent_topics_df.columns)], ignore_index=True)
            else:
                break
    sent_topics_df.columns = ['Dominant_Topic', 'Perc_Contribution', 'Topic_Keywords']
    # Add original text to the end of the output
    contents = pd.Series(texts)
    sent_topics_df = pd.concat([sent_topics_df, contents], axis=1)
    return(sent_topics_df)
df_topic_sents_keywords = format_topics_sentences(ldamodel=ldamodel, corpus=textCorpus, texts=docCollTexts)
# Format
df_dominant_topic = df_topic_sents_keywords.reset_index()
df_dominant_topic.columns = ['Document_No', 'Dominant_Topic', 'Topic_Perc_Contrib', 'Keywords', 'Text']
# Show
df_dominant_topic.head(10)
```

error
`AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py in _finalize_columns_and_data(content, columns, dtype)
938     try:
--> 939         columns = _validate_or_indexify_columns(contents, columns)
940     except AssertionError as err:

6 frames
AssertionError: 0 columns passed, passed data had 3 columns

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py in *finalize_columns_and_data(content, columns, dtype)
940     except AssertionError as err:
941         # GH#26429 do not raise user-facing AssertionError
--> 942         raise ValueError(err) from err
943
944     if len(contents) and contents[0].dtype == np.object*:

ValueError: 0 columns passed, passed data had 3 columns`

the table should look like this
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJSP9.png)

I to use concat instead of append

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. Please read [ask] for tips like how to write a good title and [not posting pictures of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). For related tips, see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341).